# Why is my wlan0 interface on Angstrom (Beagleboard) "Not Associated"?

Tags: linux, wifi, embedded, angstrom, wlan

I'm installing a Angstrom (custom build, not the default build) on a Beagleboard XM.

I can scan for wireless networks using `iwlist` and see the neighborhood wireless devices.

I have set my SSID and Key (a 10-digit hex code using lowercase) in `/etc/network/interfaces`

When I do a `ifup wlan0`, it goes through the process of `DHCPDISCOVER` and then says

> No DHCPOFFERS received.

The device is an Alfa USB with a Realtek rtl8187 chipset. (which works fine when used under Debian on my laptop).

Why isn't my SSID displayed properly under `iwconfig`, and why won't the interface get an IP via DHCP?

Comment: Is the router providing the network allowing just any MAC addresses to join or does your machine's MAC need to be granted access?

Comment: @slm: The router does not filter based on MAC addresses.  (any device can join)   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @slm for sending me to the how-to reference.

It appears the biggest issue was that `NetworkManager` was running and because I have no GUI (the BeagleBoard version of `nmcli` does not have the "connect" feature allowing for the creating of new interfaces on the command-line, and I am only connecting to the beagleboard via a serial port (no GUI)) I had no means to setup new connections.  Further, `NetworkManager` *may* have been killing connections which I was finally able to see proof of in `/var/log/syslog`.

So the solution was to prevent `NetworkManager` from running and run and setup manually the necessary configuration for `wpa_supplicant`.

With `wpa_supplicant` running and `NetworkManager` not running (and bringing the interface up/down several times) I was finally able to get a DHCP assigned, and the Internet is now reachable through a wireless connection on the Beagleboard.

I'll have to continue to fiddle and experiment to ensure this connection comes up smoothly at boot-time (and to ensure that the Ethernet port will continue to work) but at least I've overcome the immediate road-block.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this tutorial that shows how to setup a wifi client. Specifically the section on setting it up via the command-line as you're trying to do.

Tutorial's titled: [WiFiHowToUse](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse), specifically this [section](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Command_Line). There are some slight differences in the steps outlined in this tutorial from what you've described thus far in your question. For example you'll need to make sure that you have the package wpa_supplicant installed and configured correctly.

Also the tutorial references a file as `/etc/network/interfaces` not `/etc/network/interface` as you've described.

Comment: Thanks - I will check it out. My file reference was a typo... I will update - thanks